# Laravel Dusk and memory usage - how to close the browser and custom process

Tags: php, laravel, webdriver, out-of-memory, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel Dusk in the controller for users to get screenshots of the any website using mine website.

My code:

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Dusk\ElementResolver;
use Exception;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Laravel\Dusk\Chrome\ChromeProcess;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

use Mail;

class ScreenController extends Controller {
    public function take_screenshoot() {

        $process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
        if ($process->isStarted()) {
          $process->stop();
        }
        $process->start();

        $options      = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--headless',
                '--window-size=1920,1080',
                '--no-sandbox'
            ]);
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

              $driver = retry(5, function () use ($capabilities) {
          return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities, 50000, 60000);
        }, 50);

        $browser = new Browser($driver, new ElementResolver($driver, ''));
        $browser->resize(1920, 1080);
        $browser->visit('http://www.example.com')->mouseover('iframe');

        $screenshoot_name = md5(time());
        $browser->driver->takeScreenshot(base_path('tests/Browser/screenshots/'.$screenshoot_name.'.png'));
        echo "<img src='/tests/Browser/screenshots/".$screenshoot_name.".png></img>";

        $process->stop();


      }
```

Everything works well here as expected just memory usage is by each user request (user visit) higher and higher... How to solve that problem? Why `$process->stop();` do not close the browser?

[image]

***UPDATE***
I tried:

```
$browser->quit();
```

and

```
$browser->driver->quit();
```

but I got error:

> Facebook \ WebDriver \ Exception \ WebDriverCurlException Curl error
>   thrown for http DELETE to /session/8a4f02f2d13648ccfbdead97b338e4f4
>   Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

**UPDATE 2.0**
This is what I got when I run

```
# ps -aux | less
```

[image]

Comment: The only way I found is to turn OFF server and then turn ON again but that's not long term solution

Comment: @thisiskelvin APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:S6/heKijvfw8KB2K10vY77777hUhVYB1ZdzUhPEbqo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: Thank you, posting an answer which may help

Comment: have you tried gc after each request? `gc_collect_cycles()`

Comment: @MisaGH Unfortunately it doesn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 killall -o 1m chrome
```

is the right answer ... It will delete all chrome 'zombie' process older than 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues using a package which wrapped chrome. What I ended up doing is running this on the commands line:

```
pkill -f -- "chromium-browser"
```

This killed all processes which contained `chromium-browser` in it. I'm sure there is a way to add this to the code to fire once completed.

Comment: I tried this but it's not a solution for me and actually, it doesn't close browser window

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue and ended up solving it adding:

```
$browser->quit();
$process->stop();
```

**Note that the order matters**. If I swap the lines I get the same error that you mentioned:

```
Facebook \ WebDriver \ Exception \ WebDriverCurlException Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/8a4f02f2d13648ccfbdead97b338e4f4 Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem recently. Take some inspiration from the `ProvidesBrowser` trait, used by PhpUnit. During the tear-down it calls `quit()` on each browser instance. For performance sake, they're left open for reuse unless explicitly told to shut down, and will keep a connection open until then or it times out.